# How to build a Flutter voice call application without using a third-party SDK?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to build a voice call application using Flutter, I have searched for solutions but all of them use SDK and need to pay a fee, I want to create it myself but there is no any documentation I can find to guide me on this, if you have any way, please let me know, I appreciate your contribution.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using these following :

1. [Jitsi Meet](https://github.com/gunschu/jitsi_meet)
2. [flutter-webrtc](https://github.com/flutter-webrtc/flutter-webrtc)